# Need Explain: Write a program that reads an decimal number between 0 and 2G and displays the 32-bit binary version on the video display

Tags: c++, c, binary, decimal, pseudocode

```
Write a program that reads an decimal number between 0 and 2G and 
displays the 32-bit binary version on the video display
```

Someone ask me that question, ok 0 is 0 but I need EXPLAIN here what does **"2G"** mean and what is **"32-bit binary version on the video display"** any difference with normal 32-bit binary(32 number 1 and 0)?

Note: No any coding related here. Thank you guys!

Comment: Why didn't you ask back the questioner these doubts? You should not agree to answer a question unless atleast you understand the question.

Comment: asker asked me can not understand question at all sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can determine,

2G is the maximum representable 32-bit signed value, aka 2147483647, expressed as 0 followed by 31 1's.

> 32-bit binary version on the video display" any difference with normal 32-bit binary(32 number 1 and 0)?

No difference as best I can tell.

Comment: the 2G infor is very helpful!

Comment: Minor nitpick: I would say that 2G is 2147483648. (So the interval 0-2G should in this case be interpreted as not including the upper limit.)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I just used INT_MAX from climits.h . :-\  http://ideone.com/tedqU